# IIS - Get real IP address behind CloudFlare?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an IIS website that was CloudFlare, and it hides the real IP of my web server, however it also hides the real IP of all my visitors to my website. How would I get the real IP of my vistors? I have seen ways to do it but it is for a different web server program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full Answer can be found here : https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170666-How-do-I-correct-visitor-IP-with-Microsoft-IIS-

tl,dr: You need to install a module and configure it (in IIS 7).

If IIS 8+, it's built-in but it will only make the visitor IP address visible to the IIS Server, not to the applications being hosted.

If I read it correctly, it should still available in the header of the requests ("CF-Connecting-IP").

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, but https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#iis requires  F5XFFHttpModule.dll and Install-XFF.ps1

Comment: It's here https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/x-forwarded-for-http-module-for-iis7-source-included and here too https://github.com/techiemac/F5XFFHttpModule/tree/master/F5XFFHttpModule-Source

Comment: I have downloaded the ps1 file from here https://github.com/techiemac/F5XFFHttpModule/tree/master/F5XFFHttpModule-Source and the .dll from here http://devcentral.f5.com/downloads/joe/F5XFFHttpModule.zip and then put the files in C:\HttpModules and then ran .\Install-XFF.ps1 -cmd install -module_path c:\HttpModules\F5XFFHttpModule.dll
from the folder in cmd. It opened the PS1 file in Notepad. The IPs in the logs still appear to be from CloudFlare when put into a IP Lookup service.

Comment: I used a different PS1 file, enabled scripts in PowerShell, and now I see IPs that are not from CloudFlare! Thanks!